# Calculating the levenshtein distance between multiple strings

Tags: java, spring-boot, arangodb, levenshtein-distance, aql

I am trying to calculate the levenshtein distance between multiple strings (with about million strings) at once using AQL. However, the query just freezes for hours without any progress. Is there a way to do the same in Java? I am looking for an example which can help me the best in this case of diff-ing multiple strings at once without an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Apache commons

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html

But this was already answered here

[Problems with Levenshtein algorithm in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564464/problems-with-levenshtein-algorithm-in-java)